# How to create a filter on 2 fields in an alias?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, elastic-cloud

I am looking to create an alias of an index that would retrieve information according to one of 2 filters. One or the other, an "OR" in fact.

For example:

```
PUT .internal.alerts-security.alerts-jse-000001/_alias/.alerts-security.alerts-global-overview {
  "filter": {
    "terms": {
      "data_stream.namespace": [
        "etu"
      ]
    }
  }  
}
```

**or**

```
PUT .internal.alerts-security.alerts-jse-000001/_alias/.alerts-security.alerts-global-overview {
  "filter": {
    "terms": {
      "agent.name": [
        "ec6b600226d0",
        "b26a7b13a8bd"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use a `bool/should` constraint between the two filters:

```
PUT .internal.alerts-security.alerts-jse-000001/_alias/.alerts-security.alerts-global-overview
{
  "filter": {
    "bool": {
      "minimum_should_match": 1,
      "should": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "agent.name": [
              "ec6b600226d0",
              "b26a7b13a8bd"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "data_stream.namespace": [
              "etu"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```